# Set a table field to zero based on a date in another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with columns `Date` and `Amount`:

```
CustID    Date        Amount
1         20150301    10000
1         20150302    5000
1         20150303    15000
2         20150208    9000
2         20150201    5000
2         20150202    6000
```

I want to set `Amount` to zero when `Date` is after a certain date. After update it should look as follows:

```
CustID    Date        Amount
1         20150301    10000
1         20150302    0
1         20150303    0
2         20150208    0
2         20150201    5000
2         20150202    0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, min(date) over (partition by CustId) as mindate
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set amount = 0
    where date > mindate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query that checks if `date` is not equal to `MIN(Date)`:

```
UPDATE Mytable
SET Amount = 0
FROM Mytable AS t
WHERE [date] <> (SELECT MIN([Date]) 
                 FROM Mytable
                 WHERE CustId = t.CustID)
```

or, alternatively, use a `CTE`:

```
;WITH MIN_CTE AS (
   SELECT MIN([Date]) AS MinDate, CustID
   FROM Mytable 
   GROUP BY CustID
)
UPDATE Mytable
SET Amount = 0
FROM Mytable AS t
INNER JOIN MIN_CTE AS c ON t.CustID = c.CustID
WHERE t.[Date] <> c.MinDate
```

Comment: You can remove the GROUP BY from the first's sub-select.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, of course, thank you. I have updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

we can do update but here I'm showing same in select statement with row_number and MIN function also...

```
declare @t table (custid int,datet date,Amount int) 
insert into @t(custid,datet,Amount)values (1,'20150301',10000)
insert into @t(custid,datet,Amount)values (1,'20150302',5000)
insert into @t(custid,datet,Amount)values (1,'20150303',15000)
insert into @t(custid,datet,Amount)values (2,'20150208',9000)
insert into @t(custid,datet,Amount)values (2,'20150201',5000)
insert into @t(custid,datet,Amount)values (2,'20150202',4000)

;with CTE AS
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY custid order by datet )RN from @t
)
Select custid,datet,case when RN = 1 then amount ELSE 0 END Amt from cte
```

OR

```
;with CTE AS
(
select *,min(datet)OVER(PARTITION BY custid )RN from @t
)
Select custid,datet,case when RN = MIN(datet) then amount ELSE 0 END Amt from cte
group by  custid,datet,Amount,RN
```